# Spring: Is there any annonation about not repeadable data?

Tags: spring, database

For example I have a category entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category{

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="category_name")
private string name;
}
```

I want an annonation to when I try to save a category with name currently exits in category table name column, not to allow to do.
if there is no annonation, how can i not allow data to repeat

Comment: When duplicate names are not allowed from a business perspective, then you need to put a UniqueConstraint upon the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Column(unique = true)` is a way to go.